# How to add a value to a specified index of array

Tags: java

I tried to add an integer to the 4th index of the array. But it is adding after remove the 4th element.

```
int ar[] = {1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9};       
int position = 4;
for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
if(i==position){
        ar[i] = 6;
}
System.out.println(ar[i]);
}
```

Comment: What? Index 4 is 5th position. This works as expected.

Comment: The size of the array is fixed. Use `ArrayList` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing the fifth item with the number six.  A faster way to do it would be:

```
ar[position] = 6;
```

Since you are using Java, I would try to use an arraylist.  They have methods that let you add items at a given index.  If you can't do that, you will need to shift everything over.

```
int previous = 6;
int current = 0;
for(int i=position;i<ar.length;i++){
    current = ar[i];
    ar[i] = previous;
    previous = current;
}
```

If your array is full you will lose the last number though.

Answer (score 1):

Array indexing start from `0`, So to insert in 4th place you have to do `array[3] = value`. So, you'll have to put `position = 3`

```
int position = 3; // array index start from 0
```

Also, since you're using an array, while adding, you'll replace it. If you want to add without replacement, use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Refer to this [ArrayList Examples](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/example-of-arraylist-in-java-tutorial.html) if you're unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 1):

With the following line of code

```
ar[i] = 6;
```

you are assigning the value `6` to the element at index `i`. You aren't adding a new element and expecting the array to shift all other positions. **An array is of fixed size.** If you want a data structure that can grow, use an `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9));
int position = 4;
    ar.add(i, 6);   
System.out.println(ar);
```

The `add(int, T)` method shifts all elements at the current `i` index to the right and inserts the specified element at `i`. The above will print

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

You would need to insert at index `5`.

Answer (score -1):

```
int position = 3; Array starts from 0. 4th index points the fifth value.

int position = 3;
if(ar.length > position)
  {
     ar[position] = 6;
  }
```